# クーポンコードを使って割引率を決める

Tags: php

クーポンコードを使って割引率を決めたいのですが、discount2.phpの46行目とdescountForm2.phpの40行目のエラー該当箇所を見ても解決方法がわかりません。
htdocsの中にsaledata.phpとdiscountForm2.phpとdiscount2.phpとutil.phpが並列して入っています。
どなたかご教示頂けると幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

エラーコード

```
[27-Jul-2018 08:51:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getCouponRate() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/discountForm2.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/discountForm2.php on line 40
[27-Jul-2018 08:52:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getCouponRate() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/discount2.php:46
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/discount2.php on line 46
```

saledata.php

```
<php
    //販売データ
    $couponList = [ "nf23qw"=>0.75, "ha45as"=>0.8, "hf56zx"=>8.5];
    $priceList = [ "ax101"=>2300, "ax102"=>2900];


     function getCouponRate($code) {
        global $couponList;

        $isCouponCode = array_key_exists($code, $couponList);
        if ($isCouponCode) {
            return $couponList[$code];
        } else {

            return NULL;
            }
    }


    function getPrice($id) {
         global $priceList;

    $isGoodsID = array_key_exists ($id, $priceList);
    if ($isGoodsID) {
         return $priceList[$id];
    } else {

    return NULL;
    }    
 }   

  ?>
```

discount2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>金額の計算</title>
     <link href=" ../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php
       require_once("util.php");

       if (!cken($_POST)) {
           $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
           $err = "Encoding Error! The expected encoding is " . $encoding ;

           exit($err);
       }

       $_POST = es($_POST);
?>

<?php

       $errors = [];

     if (isset($_POST[ 'couponCode' ])) {
     $couponCode = $_POST[ 'couponCode' ];
      } else {

      $couponCode = "";
      }

     if (isset($_POST[ 'goodsID' ])) {
         $goodsID = $_POST[ 'goodsID' ];
    } else {   

        $goodsID = "";
       }
?>

<?php

     require_once("saledata.php");

      $discount = getCouponRate($couponCode);
      $tanka = getPrice($goodsID);

     if (is_null($discount) || is_null($tanka)) {

       $err = '<div class="error">不正な操作がありました。</div>';
      exit($err);
      }
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST[ 'kosu' ])) {
$kosu = $_POST[ 'kosu' ];

if (!ctype_digit($kosu)) {

$errors[] = "個数は整数で入力して下さい。";
    }
   } else {

   $errors[] = "個数が未設定";
    }
?>

<?php
if (count($errors)>0) {

echo '<ol class="error">';
foreach ($errors as $value) {
   echo "<li>" , $value , "</li>";
   }
   echo "</ol>";
} else {

$price = $tanka * $kosu;
$discount_price = floor($price * $discount);
$off_price = $price - $discount_price;
$off_per = (1- $discount)*100;

$tanka_fmt = number_format($tanka);
$discount_price_fmt = number_format($discount_price);
$off_price_fmt = number_format($off_price);

echo "単価:{$tanka_fmt}円、", "個数:{$kosu}個", "<br>";
echo "金額:{$discount_price_fmt}円", "<br>";
echo "(割引:-{$off_price_fmt}円、{$off_per}% OFF)", "<br>";
}
?>


<form method="POST" action="discountForm2.php">

          <input type="hidden" name="kosu" value="<?php echo $kosu; ?>">
    <ul>
          <li><input type="submit" value="戻る" ></li>
   </ul>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

discountForm2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>割引購入ページ</title>
<link href=" ../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div>
       <?php
          require_once("util.php");

         if (!cken($_POST)){
              $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
              $err = "Encoding Error! The expected encoding is " . $encoding;

              exit($err);
          }

           $_POST = es($_POST);
    ?>

<?php


      if (isset($_POST[ 'kosu' ])) {
          $kosu = $_POST[ 'kosu' ];
      } else {
          $kosu = "";
      }
?>

<?php

       require_once("saledata.php");

         $couponCode = "ha45as";
         $goodsID = "ax102";

      $discount = getCouponRate($couponCode);
      $tanka = getPrice($goodsID);

      if (is_null($discount) || is_null($tanka)) {

     $err = '<div class="error">不正な操作がありました。</div>';
      exit($err);
       }
?>

<?php
      $off = (1 - $discount) * 100;
      if ($discount>0) {
           echo "<h2>このページでのご購入は{$off}% OFFになります！</h2>";
       }

  $tanka_fmt = number_format($tanka);
  ?>


  <form method="POST" action="discount2.php">

  <input type="hidden" name="couponCode" value="<?php echo $couponCode; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="goodsID" value="<?php echo $goodsID; ?>">
  <ul>
     <li><label>単価:<?php echo $tanka_fmt; ?>円</label></li>
     <li><label>個数:
           <input type="number" name="kosu">
    </label></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="計算する" ></li>
 </ul>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `saledata.php` の先頭部分が `<php` となっていて `?` が抜けていますが、これは写し間違いでしょうか？

Comment: すいません。抜けてました。 ?をつけて全ては解決しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/138162

Comment: @アフロ 解決した場合はコメントで済ませず、「自己回答」を投稿して他のユーザーにも分かるようにしてください。

Answer (score 1):

?をつけて解決しました！
宜しくお願いします。